# Laravel, AngularJS and SEO

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5, seo

I am developing an app with an AngularJS front end and a Laravel API backend. The Laravel backend just listens for requests, process them and returns an answer. Front and back end are different independent apps... so far. I did it in such a way in order to be able to develop a mobile app later on which could consume the API. Im using also JWT to authenticate users, so Im not using Laravel's sessions at all. At this point I only require a webapp. I built a webapp which uses angular ui-router.

So far so good. The front end and the back end work well. However some of the front end views will be public and require share buttons, they also require to be indexable by Google.

I've read there are some alternatives.

1. [Make some hack](http://www.michaelbromley.co.uk/blog/171/enable-rich-social-sharing-in-your-angularjs-app) using the apache mod_rewrite in order to serve the angular app for people and a static version of it served directly by the backend. I think this would not be very difficult using Laravel.
2. Using Prerender.js. Which as far as Im concerned does pretty much the same job than option 1 but in a more complete manner.

However I am thinking about using a third alternative. Given that I only require the webapp now and the API is working I am thinking about using Laravel's built-in webapp functionality. I can use the controllers, directives and factories from angular and let Laravel handle the webapp routing.

An advantage of this is that I can render the meta tags using Blade (this fixes completely the SEO issues) and serve the rest of the contents using angular and the API.

Do anyone of you can see drawacks of such a solution or do you know a better way to accomplish SEO purposes using angular and Laravel?

Comment: Not sure if I understood it right, but if I did you're planning on moving away from ui-route (AngularJS) to Laravel Route, which requires a GET. With ui-route you can build SPA and remove the constant GET request from a time where the internet had no other option. I'm just pointing this out to make you well aware, maybe you don't mind this, but if it were me, I would.

Comment: Hi @MarcoAurélioDeleu. I have been experimenting and learning ui-route. I find it quite useful (and not so easy to learn). I know that would be an issue. However I am trying to tell if that is a good trade off. That would not be an SPA but I would have some of the power of Blade and Laravel on my views. I will still use angular on each view to do all the other jobs angular is good at (ajax, dom access, etc.) but leave routing to Laravel. The webapp would still make calls to the API but the SEO and routing will be far more easy to handle?

Comment: I understand your concerns and for me just the fact that Laravel Routing would kill the SPA concept is enough to give up on it. But that's totally a opinion-based answer and it's quite hard for you to get a technical answer out of this unless someone knows a way to get the best of each.

Comment: @Jonathan I know it's late but did you ever figure this one out? I am in the same situation here.

Comment: @Wonka I divided my project into two elements: the front desk and the back office. The back office is a single page app handled only by angular and powered by the API with JWT. The back office requires no indexing whatsoever, it is just a user dashboard. In the front desk I used Laravel routes and Blade. In a template I loaded the same js script which contains the Angular app. The login view, the register view and any other public view rendered the meta tags in the backend using Blade and Laravel. The requests were handled by the Angular app. Each public page loaded "its own" Angular app.

Comment: @Jonathan Thank you for showing a possible solution for dual integration :)

Comment: I used Laravel to route requests. When any route required a view, the view loaded the corresponding Angular view. So far it works well. I use PHP to set the tags for SEO purposes and then let the Angular views to handle everything else, such as contacting the backend to retrieve views data, submitting forms or showing or hiding views subelements.

Answer (score 0):

Render Site :

You will have to render the pages from server side if you want to make it SEO friendly. But yes, what if you serve the server rendered pages to bots only. And for real users client side rendering will work.

Read about the [`Rendertron`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/rendertron) which will detect the user agent and accordingly serve the html.

Meta Tags :

Use [`Sluggable`](https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable) and replace id with slug in urls. You can follow https://oodavid.com/article/angularjs-meta-tags-management/