# Cannot find module '../dist/ngfactory/src/app/app.server.module.ngf actory'. angular cli

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-universal

I wanted to make my angular app seo friendly so I searched google and found several solutions [Make your Angular App SEO-Friendly (Angular 4 + Universal)](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/68/Make-your-Angular-App-SEO-Friendly-(Angular-4-+-Universal)) I follow the instructions however when I run the project with npm run start the following error occurred:

```
src/server.ts(5,42): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../dist/ngfactory/src/app/app.server.module.ngf
actory'.
```

I search entire day looking for solution I read this issue[[AOT] @ngtools/webpack throws "Cannot find module './ngfactory/app/app.module.ngfactory'"](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2586) however my problem didn't solve my problem all of my packages are the latest version and this is my 
build commmand inside package.json

```
"prestart": "ng build --prod && ./node_modules/.bin/ngc",
"start": "ts-node src/server.ts",
```

here is server.ts file:

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import { platformServer, renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server'
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core'
import { AppServerModuleNgFactory } from '../dist/ngfactory/src/app/app.server.module.ngfactory'
import * as express from 'express';
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
import { join } from 'path';

const PORT = 4200;

enableProdMode();

const app = express();

let template = readFileSync(join(__dirname, '..', 'dist', 'index.html')).toString();

app.engine('html', (_, options, callback) => {
  const opts = { document: template, url: options.req.url };

  renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, opts)
    .then(html => callback(null, html));
});

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', 'src')

app.get('*.*', express.static(join(__dirname, '..', 'dist')));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { req });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`listening on http://localhost:${PORT}!`);
});
```

Comment: Mb this is problem with your project modules structure. Provide it pls.

Comment: What do you mean by project module structure?

Comment: Ok, provide pls server.ts file

Comment: I provided it in my question statement

Comment: have you got the solution /

Comment: No, unfortunately, I couldn't find any solution for this question

Comment: Any Luck ? We have another solution rendertron. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36189498/laravel-angularjs-and-seo/52199883#52199883.
And please suggest if any other solution you found.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if it will help or not but you can Try To Put (./) 
in "start" : "th-node ./",

```
"prestart": "ng build --prod && ./node_modules/.bin/ngc",
"start": "ts-node ./src/server.ts"
```